# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent in loop multiple request

Tags: node.js, express

i'm beginner at nodejs,  i got a problem when request multiple url in a loop then i render it.

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)

at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:)


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  setInterval(function(){

             request(url1,function (error,response,body) {
                 var data1 = JSON.parse(body);

                 request(url2+data1.access_token,function (error,response,body) {
                 var data_info = JSON.parse(body);

                                   //error when it render
                               res.render('index', {data_info : data_info});
                            })
                        })
          },5000);
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [Async Module](https://caolan.github.io/async/)

```
const async = require('async');
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   async.waterfall([
       function(callback) {
           request(url1, function (error,response,body) {
               if(err) {
                   callback(err)
               }else {
                    var data1 = JSON.parse(body);
                    callback(data1)
               }

           }) 
       },
       function(data1, callback) {
           request(url2+data1.access_token, function(error,response,body) {
                if(err) {
                   callback(err)
               }else {
                   var data_info = JSON.parse(body);
                    callback(null, data_info)
               }
           }) 
       }
   ], function(err, result) {
       if(err) {
           res.json({success: false, error: err, message: "Something went wrong.!"})
       }else {
            res.render('index', {
                data_info : result
            });
       }
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not exactly a loop, I understand you mean that you call the same function repeteadly with `setInterval()`.

Once you've sent your first response with `res.render()`, which finishes the response process for that request, subsequent attempts to use that `res` object fail.

If you want to send data to the client in 5 seconds interval you should probably either look into [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or pass the `setInterval()` calls to the client so it polls your server each 5 seconds, in which case your server code could be changed to:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  request(url1, (error, response, body) => {
    const data1 = JSON.parse(body);
    request(`${url2}${data1.access_token}`, (error, response, body) => {
      const data_info = JSON.parse(body);
      res.render('index', { data_info });
    });
  });
});
```